# API Friends list count different than number on Facebook

Tags: facebook, list, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching list of friends in Graph API or FQL - Appears to be missing some friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend)

I've got 364 friends, but using FB Api to retrieve my friends list (using something like FB.api('/me/friends', function(response)...), Facebook returns me only 362 friends. I don't know why. Any suggestions?
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Use FQL:

```
SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me();
```

Replace me() with the FB user id you like.

Here is a Graph API Explorer [sample](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20friend_count%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20me%28%29;).

Comment: Close, but not really a duplicate. FQL returns correct total friend count, which matches with the number on FB profile.

But, the list of friends returned by the Graph API and FQL are the same, and are restricted by the privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

2 of your friends have different privacy permissions regarding your application's right to find them in search