# Fetching list of friends in Graph API or FQL - Appears to be missing some friends

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Any chance the `'me/friends'` graph api or `friends` FQL table return *some* friends only?

I've checked the results and it's slightly less than the count I see on facebook.com

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### In Graph API V1.0

A call to `/friends` on a [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) (e.g. `/me/friends`) or a query of the [`friend` FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) should return all friends of that user except

1. Those who have [deactivated their accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/214376678584711)
2. Those who have [blocked your app](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=16976)
3. Those who have disabled all Platform apps from accessing their data. - If a user enables this option (see below) you can't access any information about that user via the API, including their basic info, posts they make, etc. They **won't** appear in the friends list of your app's user via the API.

If you find friends are missing from the response it's almost certainly for one of those reasons, and in my experience most people asking this question are asking about the third case.

---

The option to remove platform option is currently under *Privacy Settings -> Ads, Apps & Websites -> 'Turn off your ability to use apps, plugins, and websites on and off Facebook*

If you're not getting all friends in a single call and you're sure it's not because of one of those reasons, check if you have a `limit` parameter in your query - and increase it if it's less than the number of friends you think should be appearing.

e.g. `/me/friends?limit=5000` for the maximum number of friends allowed, 5000

Note that the friends count will include users which can't be retrieved in the list (e.g. the `friend_count` field of the User FQL table)

### In Graph API V2.0 or higher

A call to `/friends` on a User object will, if the user has granted your app the `user_friends` permission, return the friends of that user who have also granted your app the `user_friends` permission -

You can read more about the change from v1.0 to v2.0 in [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m) or on [Facebook's changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a limit parameter.
`'me/friends/?limit=0'` it will return all your friends.

> UPDATE

the parameter `limit=0` returns 0 friends,
to get all your friends, you need to set the `limit=5000` (it's the max number allowed)

Comment: The answer is wrong. `limit=0` does not mean no limit, it means return 0 friends. Just have a try and you will see.

Comment: @TylerLong this answer it's a bit old and doesn't work any more. Updated now!

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of the `Facebook Graph API 2.0`, access a user's friends list was removed and limited to just friends who use the same application. However, Facebook added two new APIs to allow retrieval of Friend names (and indirectly a friend count). The two new APIs are `taggable_friends` and `invitable_friends`.

```
Url:
me/taggable_friends?limit=1&fields=id,name,
```