# Can't get more than 100 friends profiles with facebook using Spring social

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to access to my friends profiles on facebook using Spring social. It works fine but it seems there is a limit to the number of profiles recovered : I can't get more than 100 profiles (with my account or with a test account).

I saw that it is possible to set a limit the number of datas recovered on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend) but I didn't see it anywhere in spring social facebook api.

So, do you know if this is something to manage via facebook or if this is a default setting with spring social ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble came from the version I used, i upgraded dependencies to 1.0.3.RELEASE and it works.