# Facebook API - count friends returning non consistent values

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

trying to get amount of facebook firiends via facebook api (PHP)

- using this API call :

  ```
                  $friends=$facebook->api('/me?fields=friends');
                  $friends=$friends['friends']; 
                  $amount = count($friends);
                  //$amount = 477
  ```
- using this API call :

  ```
                  $params = array(
                                  'method' => 'fql.query',
                                  'query' => "SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid =me()",
                  );
                  $amount = $facebook->api($params);
                  //$amount = 488
  ```
- Why is there a difference for both the calls ?
- What is more accurate ?
- Is there a way to overcome this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: And the `friend` table is giving the same result as `GraphAPI` using the query: `SELECT uid2 FROM friend  WHERE uid1 =me()` . I'm not sure why is this happening, but the result from `fql` query is correct!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching list of friends in Graph API or FQL - Appears to be missing some friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend)

Comment: Already covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend