# Appcelerator Titanium: Facebook Graph API empty Friends list

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator

another problem with the Facebook connection from Titanium.

I make an request to Facebook with Graph API, but I only get an empty result:

> SUCCESS; {"data":[]}

This is my code:

```
Ti.App.fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/friends', false, 'GET', showRequestResult);
```

I've also tried to use the request example from KitchenSink, but that's not working, because the method is turned for my FB SDK.

So, I've tried to update the permissions for facebook with "user_friends" but if I log in, it's not asking for this permission.

Any Ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26889136/3419997) would be helpful

Comment: mhm, I've also tried invitable friends, same result.

Comment: i've made it, i need the permission user_friends to load the friends and i didn't put this permission in the right variable, so that was the only problem and my code works perfect. thank you for your time ;)

Comment: You should write your solution as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. So people know the question is completed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work was that i have to get the Facebook permission "user_friends".